# Clicking on Twitter favorite button via Selenium has no effect

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, web-scraping

I was using a Python script to log into my Twitter account and click the favorite button of each tweet on my timeline. Even though the button element can be located and console output shows every button has been clicked, there seems to be no effect at all - when I log into my account to check I found no tweet has been "liked". Do anybody have a clue how the favorite mechanism works?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import sys
import codecs
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)

def login_twitter(username, password, driver):

    username_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-username-field")
    password_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-password-field")

    username_field.send_keys(username)
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)

    password_field.send_keys(password)
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)

    driver.find_element_by_class_name("EdgeButtom--medium").click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    print("Login OK")

    elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ProfileTweet-action--favorite")

    print("Found " + str(len(elements)) + " elements")

    for e in elements:
        try:
            print("Waiting for element to be visible")
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of(e))
            print("clicking " + str(e))
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(e).click().perform()
            print("clicked " + str(e.text))
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = input("user name : ")
    password = getpass("password  : ")

    display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 2048))
    display.start()

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")

    try:
        login_twitter(username, password, driver)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

    driver.quit()
    display.stop()
```

Comment: You seem to be clicking a span element, that does not do much. Try clicking the button element (classname: `ProfileTweet-actionButton js-actionButton js-actionFavorite` at least in my browser)

Comment: Indeed, using `elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ProfileTweet-actionButton.js-actionButton.js-actionFavorite")` solved the issue. Thank you!!